# Window 10 pc takes 3 times to reboot

Tags: windows-10, boot, troubleshooting, reboot

This is a goofy issue and I'm not sure how to diagnose / fix it. On the occasion I need to restart my pc, this is how it has to go

**start button > power > restart**

**1) computer reboots to black screen**

- no mouse / keyboard ui visible
- vnc will connect but not usable, not even ctrl+alt+del
- quick press of pc case power btn does nothing.
- have to press and hold power button to turn pc off

**2) next boot is again to black screen**

- same symptoms as above except now a quick press of the power button turns off the computer.

**3) third boot works as expected**

It's always this order of restarts and symptoms. How can I diagnose and fix what is going on ?

*notes*

- quick boot is disabled
- this seemed to happen shortly after enabled WSL for windows 10
- my computer is set to "never" sleep
- in the morning the pc usually shut off and I have to go through the process of the 3 restarts
- I'm going to attempt a backup, reformat to see if these issues go away

Comment: It sounds like a power supply issue, something in the chain isn't starting up as quickly or as well as it should. The first thing to do would be to try an new power supply, otherwise it could be a motherboard fault or overloaded PSU.

Comment: Try removing your video card or any portable HDD/Flash Drive to troubleshoot.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the CMOS battery?

Comment: This has been happening for a while so I replaced the PSU and the video card :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

**Moved my monitor from Display Port plug 3 to Display Port plug 1**

*Troubleshooting Notes Below*

My video card, an nvidia RTX 2070 has the following display outputs:

```
[ DisplayPort ] [ DisplayPort ] [ HDMI ] [ DisplayPort ]
```

My monitor, an Apple Cinema Display, is using a mini display port to display port adapter and was plugged into the furthest right display port (display port 3).

Upon boot, it appeared windows was loading but I was never presented with the windows login screen. Eventually I noticed my machine was available via VNC Viewer, which meant VNC Server was running on my machine, which meant windows startup was completing. I used my laptop and VNC Viewer to connect to the PC with the display issue ultimately being presented with a "blank" view, a black screen with a little white box as the mouse curosr. Recently at work I had VNC'd into a computer without a monitor plugged into it and was presented with this same "blank" view. With some research I found this "blank" view is a window OS level feature where the OS doesn't bother rendering display data when there is no display connected.

Recently when my computer booted blank again I unplugged my monitor, plugged it back in, and it worked. Ultimately I found that if I use the first display port the my monitor is always detected (so far).

**Thanks to everyone who offered a solution and I help this helps someone down the road.**

** EDIT **

This just happened to me again for the first time in a while. It looks like it doesn't matter the display port but the solution is still to unplug / plug back in the monitor. I'm certain this is to do my adapter.